# How to import all databases at a time in wamp

Tags: php, mysql, database, localhost, wamp

I export whole **databases** `sql` file from localhost `wamp`. Now I want to import all databases and table by importing that one sql file. But I get sql error...database error with name...and following error. Plz give me solution for this.

`MySQL` said:

```
#1046 - No database was selected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1046 - No database was selected

This error suggests that when you dumped all these database the resulting .sql file does not contain the required `use databasename;` between each database restore.

You will have to edit the `.sql` file and add a `use databasename;` statement for each database, just before the restore changes the database it is restoring.

Answer (score 2):

First select your database, then do the import. You can modify your `sql file` with a `use databasename;` to select a database for you during import

Comment: I can't select database, bcz my sql contains all databases. Nd I tried it, it not worked.

Comment: How are u creating the dump?

Comment: I just go to myadmin home and without selecting any database I export sql file, which contains all databases.

Comment: No advanced options available like a 'Drop and create database'-option?

Comment: why drop nd create needed??

Comment: Because this way u don't need to select the correct database. After a database is created, it's going to be selected

Comment: In my phpmyadmin, no any databases. I want to import all databases and their tables by importing my sql file which contains all databases. But I get sql error.

Comment: Can you share some parts of your SQL file to see what is going on? Probably, the dump does not contain "CREATE DATABASE" statements